# Dump Kafka to GCS

Tags: apache-kafka, google-cloud-storage

Can someone help me with the best possible way to dump data from a kafka topic to Google Cloud storage?

I would like to build a near real time pipeline which is capable to creating multiple files based on time or size cuts.

Data in kafka topic is in JSON format.

Answer (score 0):

Confluent offers a GCS Kafka Connect sink, but you could also try using Google DataFlow / Apache Beam to do the same.

Comment: Thanks @OneCricketeer. As Confluent is a paid solution that is out of picture. Let me give Apache Beam a try! Thank you!.